# I want to push notification into the notification collection of mongo DB when a new user registers

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, push-notification, notifications

I am using the MERN stack. I want to push notification into the notification collection of Mongo DB when a new user gets register. Previously I have worked with firebase, and it was easy to push notification into the firestore using google cloud function. I have searched a lot but did not find the solution.

Comment: if you want to add a document in collection with registration you can check pre save hooks.

Comment: Are you using mongoose with node.js?

Comment: Yes @PuneetSingh I am using mongoose with node.js.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use pre-save hooks of mongoose, for that you need to create User Schema and Notification Schema, and then in UserSchema pre-save create a new notification as shown in below example.

```
// modals/User.js    

const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const Notification = require('./Notification.js').Notification;


var UserSchema = new Schema({
    first_name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },

    last_name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },

    ......
});

UserSchema.post('save', function(doc) {
    var NewData = new Notification({
        user_id: doc._id,
        text: "Welcome to application"
    });

    NewData.save(function(err, notification_data) {
        // any error logging or other operations
    });
});

//make this available to our users in Node applications
module.exports.User = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
```

In Notification.js, you can create schema as per your requirement.

Comment: it is not working correctly. It creates a notification collection but gives doc._id undefined.

Comment: Ok, I will try to run the code on my side, will check it in a couple of hours

Comment: Using post Middleware fixes the problem. Thanx, a lot @PuneetSingh.